# I need a refresh before my redirection, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm doing a web app, and this night, I try to make a preview of the upload image of my post.Like in the photo :

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlGGU.png)|| [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxURH.png)

And since that, I have to refresh my :edit and :new page post. If I don't do that, the page is frozen !

views/posts/_form :

```html
<div class= "posts-wrapper">
  <div class= "post">
    <div class= "post-body">
      <div class= "image-wrap">
        <%= image_tag 'placeholder.jpg', id: 'image-preview', class: 'img-responsive' %>
        <%= simple_form_for @post, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
        </div>
          <div class= "row">
            <div class= "col-md-12.text-center">
              <%= f.error_notification %>
              </div>

          <div class= "container-fluid">

            <div class= "form-group.text-center">
              <h4> Upload an image (this is required): </h4>
              <%= f.input :image, label: false, input_html: { onChange: 'loadFile(event)' } %>
              </div>

            <div class= "form-group.text-center">
              <%= f.input :caption, label: false, placeholder: 'Add your caption' %>
              </div>

            <div class= "form-group.text-center">
              <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn-success btn-block' %>

              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
          
      </div>
  </div>
  <%end%>
</div>
```

assets/js/posts.js :

```html
var loadFile = function(event) {  
  var output = document.getElementById('image-preview');
  output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
};
```

And the helpers/appli :

```html
def form_image_select(post)  
  return image_tag post.image.url(:medium),
                   id: 'image-preview',
                   class: 'img-responsive' if post.image.exists?
  image_tag 'placeholder.jpg', id: 'image-preview', class: 'img-responsive'
end
```

How I can solve this problem ?
I try a lot of things, even an automatic refresh of the page when the user is arriving, but it's so dirty !

Comment: Can you please edit your question to explain a bit more about what you're trying to do?  It's not obvious what " preview of the upload image of my post" means.  Talk through it step by step.

Comment: ok, i do that right now

Comment: Done, you can see the result with the photo

Comment: Can you try to preview a lighter picture ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this function ?

I replaced `URL.createObjectURL` by a `FileReader` call.I think your page is freezed because the object is too heavy.

```js
var loadFile = function(event) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var output = document.getElementById('image-preview');
        output.src = e.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
};

$("#file").on("change", function(e) {
    loadFile(e);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="image-preview" />
<input type="file" id="file" value="input" />
```

Edit:

in posts.js (after jquery import):

```
var loadFile = function(event) {  
  var output = document.getElementById('image-preview');
  output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#file").on("change", function(e) {
        loadFile(e);
    });
});
```

Comment: Where I have to insert the second part of code ?
I'd try to replace the first one, but the preview is not running, and I still have to refresh the page to post the comment

Comment: I updated my answer. you should remove this `onChange: 'loadFile(event)'` to use the jquery event

Comment: No sorry, the page stil not working with this solution, but thanks for your help !